# python itertools.tee - why do my copies behave this way?

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools

I have the following code:

```
# create an iterator
result = itertools.groupby(people, key=get_job)

# create copies
copy1, copy2, copy3, copy4, copy5 = itertools.tee(result, 5)

# run first copy
for key, group in copy1:
    print(key, list(group))

# run second copy
for key, group in copy2:
    print(key, list(group))
```

What comes back is:

```
hacker [list here as expected]
banker [list here as expected]
trader [list here as expected]

hacker []
banker []
trader []
```

So the second iterator fails.

I am aware that you can only iterate an iterator once in python - but isn't the point of copying *precisely to solve that problem?* Ie I'd expect each copy to have its own life, and be able to iterate over it regardless of whether I've iterated over the other ones.

Either my code is wrong or I'm misunderstand the purpose of copying.

Comment: `.groupby()` returns a two-level iterator: an outer iterator of groups, each element of which is an iterator of values belonging to that group.  `.tee()` only copied the outer iterator, each copy shares the same inner iterators.  So after fully looping through the first copy, the remaining copies consist entirely of exhausted iterators.

Comment: Super interesting, I didn't realize that. Is there a way to copy .groupby iterator objects s.t. both inner and outer get separated out?

Comment: Simplest solution would be to read the entire thing into nested lists, that you could then iterate as many times as you want - `[list(group) for group in itertools.groupby(...)]`.  This throws away the memory efficiency of generators - but you're doing that already, by using `.tee()` and then consuming one copy entirely before starting on the second copy, you're forcing the entire contents to be held in memory.

Comment: @jasonharper I tried the below - but it still returns empty iterator objects for each group:

list_of_groups = [list(group) for group in itertools.groupby(people, key=get_job)]
print(list_of_groups)
for key, group in list_of_groups:
    print(key, list(group))

What am I missing?

(Sorry I realize this is hard to read...)

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of research I can confirm that @jasonharper above was correct - you can't itertools.tee nested iterators like .groupby.

Instead I found a working solution here: [Python itertools.groupby multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450022/python-itertools-groupby-multiple-values)

Copy pasting from there to save anyone who's reading this time:

```
totalResults = [] 
totalClasses = []           
for key, location in groupby(rows, lambda k: k[0]):
    location = list(location)
    totalResults.append(dict(name=key, data=[x[2] for x in location]))
    totalClasses.append(dict(name=key, data=[x[3] for x in location]))
```

All kudos to the author (@John La Rooy) there.